# Animation Not Working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, animation, cross-browser

Not sure why this doesn't work in Firefox, the animation works fine in Webkit browsers just not FF.

I have all of the keyframes written and the transitions etc. seem to work in FF without keyframes so not sure why it doesn't when all put together.

```
 @-webkit-keyframes flip {
        from {
            -o-transform: scaleX(0);
            -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
            transform: scaleX(0);
    }
        to {
        transition-duration: 0s;
        transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(0px);
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.1);
          }
     }
    @keyframes flip {

    0% {
        -moz-transform: scaleX(0);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
        -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateX(0px);
        -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.1);
      }
    }
.jig-loaded img {
     -webkit-animation: flip 1.0s;
    animation: flip 1.0s;
    -moz-animation: flip 1.0s !important;
    opacity: 1;
 }
```